# How to understand one of the properties of satisfaction of wfs in first-order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability

Proposition:

> If the free variables (if any) of a well-formed formula $\textbf{B}$
> occur in the list $x_{i_1}, \dots, x_{i_k}$ and if the sequences $s$
> and $s^′$ have the same components in the ${i_{1}}^\text{th}, \dots,
> > {i_{k}}^{th}$ places, then $s$ satisfies $\textbf{B}$ if and only if
> $s^′$ satisfies $\textbf{B}$. Here $s$ and $s^′$ are denumerable
> sequences $s = (s_1, s_2, \dots )$ of elements from the domain $D$ of
> some interpretation $M$.

It is from Mendelson's book "Introduction to Mathematical Logic". The problem here is that I can't fully agree with the proposition, hence can't approach to prove it as it doesn't make sense to me (although obviously it is just me missing something).

My understanding is that proving this proposition will imply that satisfaction of a wf depends solely on free variables. However I think even if $s$ and $s^′$ share same elements in the same positions, assigning the rest of the different elements of sequences to corresponding bound variables in $\textbf{B}$ may lead to different results. Example:

Let $\textbf{B}$ be $(\forall x_1)(E(x_1) \wedge O(f(x_1))$, where

- $E(x_1)$ is interpreted as "*is even*"
- $O(x_1)$ as "*is odd*"
- $f(x_1)$ is "*a successor of $x_1$*"
- and the domain is a set of positive integers

Here I picked a wf without free variables which should make the initial to-be-proven proposition vacuously true. Now, let $s = (2, \dots)$ and $s^′=(4, \dots)$.  We can see that both $s$ and $s^′$ satisfy $\textbf{B}$ (2 and 4 are both even and their successor is an odd integer) just because we were lucky enough to pick the "right" sequences. However if $s^′ = (3, \dots)$, then the wf is not satisfied anymore by $s^′$. As such the proposition saying that "$s$ satisfies $\textbf{B}$ if and only if $s^′$ satisfies $\textbf{B}$" can't be true since $s^′$ fails to satisfy $\textbf{B}$ while $s$ does so.

What am I missing?

Comment: $\bf B$ has no free variables hence is satisfied either by every sequence or by none. In fact here: by none, since there are positive integers $n$ for which $E(n)\land O(f(n))$ is false (and even $E(n)$ and $O(f(n))$ are false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bf B$ has no free variables hence *is satisfied either by every sequence or by none.* In fact here: by none, since there are positive integers $n$ for which $E(n)\land O(f(n))$ is false (and even $E(n)$ and $O(f(n))$ are false).

Your $(3,\dots)$ does not satisfy $\bf B$, but neither do your $(2,\dots)$ and $(4,\dots).$

Comment: Honestly, by saying that neither my $(2, \dots)$ nor $(4, \dots)$ satisfy $\textbf{B}$ I have even more questions now. Like I totally missed everything. Can we follow-up with a few more rounds of questions? Since I am not sure what you mean precisely here. Nor I understand where you get the first statement from. I believe that "$\textbf{B}$ has no free variables hence is satisfied either by every sequence or by none" should follow from proving the proposition in the question. Doesn't it?

Comment: Not at all. Re-read Mendelson's (e.g.) definition of satisfaction. I can only agree with all the answers you already got from Shinrin-Yoku. It would be useless to repeat them, and mine are the same.

Comment: I am sorry, I am just having difficult time to understand what is it I am missing. There are a lot of hints pointing to what you say that when there are no free variables then the statement is either true or false. However, even if $\textbf{B}$ has free variables, it is still not clear how even remotely it can make sense to expect any other sequence to satisfy a statement just because they share same elements that are supposed to replace only free variables. How do I make sure that $s^′$ has elements besides common ones that would satisfy the wf?

Comment: It gets even more awkward to see that Mendelson suggests to prove the lemma first: $s^{*}(t) = {(s^′)}^{*}(t)$, when the function itself is defined as "If $t$ is a variable $x_j$, let $s^*(t)$ be $s_j$. So for $(4, \dots)$ the results for $x_1$ will be $4$, for $(2, \dots)$ it will be $2$. Can't see how that lemma is correct unless $2=4$ somehow.

Comment: If $t$ is $x_1$ (hence has $x_1$ as a free variable) and $s_1\ne s'_1,$ your $s$ and $s'$ do not satisfy the hypothesis of Mendelson's proposition, so it is not a surprise that $s^{*}(t)\ne {(s^′)}^{*}(t).$ What Mendelson says is that for instance if $\bf B$ is $P(x_1)$ (meaning it has only $x_1$ as a free variable) and if $s_1=s'_1,$ then $s$ satisfies $\bf B$ iff $s'$ does. It is quasi-tautological. It means that if $s_1=s'_1$ then $P(s_1)$ is satisfied iff $P(s'_1)$ is.

Comment: suppose $\textbf{B}$ has a free variable $x_2$ and a bound variable $x_1$. Now $s = (s_1, x_2, \dots)$ and $s^′ = (s^′_1, x_2, \dots)$ where $s_1 \ne s^′_1$ to make sequences differ from each other. Then in this case all hypothesis hold while $s^{*}(t)\ne {(s^′)}^{*}(t)$. $s_1\ne s'_1$, however it should be equal to my understanding of the lemma. What is the issue here?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov What do you mean? If $x_{2}$ is the only free variable, then the sequences match at the second position and the theorem applies.

Comment: Right. For some reason I misunderstood the lemma as if it should hold for every term, not only for those $t$ that contain free variables from the list. Hence the confusion arose. Thanks.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov You should really upvote answers, because that shows they answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula **B** is a sentence, it has no free variables. The thereom *does* hold for it and it says that for any two completely arbitrary sequences $s$, $s'$(that need not match at any place), if $s$ satisfies **B** then so does $s'$. The thing is that since **B** is a sentence its truth does not depend on any of the sequences, either it would be true for all sequences or false for all sequences, this follows from induction on wf's and the very definition of satisfaction.

Comment: Do you mean Mendelson made a mistake? Or the OP did not reproduce faithfully the book?

Comment: @Anne Bauval Oops I misread the question, you may look at my edit that gives a detailed explantion.

Comment: Ok, this now corresponds to my (previous comment transformed to an) answer.

Comment: doesn't "if the sequences $s$ and $s^′$ have the same components in the ${i_{1}}^\text{th}, \dots, {i_{k}}^{th}$ places" mean that sequences have to match at the specified places?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov No, since **B** is a sentence, it has $0$ free variables. So the matching condition holds vacuously.

Comment: @AnneBauval We may delete these comments that are no longer relevant.

Comment: okay, so is it just because of my example, right? Because from the answer I got an impression that they don't have to match at all in general which bewildered me

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov It is because **B** is a sentence, if **B** had $x_{1}$ as a free variable, then the sequences would have to match in the first position.